# Ho do I raise an event in a constructor?

Tags: c#, events, eventhandler

I have got a class, where its childs initialize and declare ObservableCollections. I wanted to collect the collections of the childs in the base class, to use then later in a generic method, so I wrote an event handler, which is raised in the constructor of a child of ObservableCollection and the handler is added in my BaseView class. Little note: A lot of child-views do already exist and I want to implement this without changing their code. My ObservableCollection child looks like this:

```
public class ObservableCollection<T> : System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public ObservableCollection()
        :base()
    {
        OnConstructorCalled(new ConstructorCalledEventArgs(this));
    } 

    public static event ConstructorCalledEventHandler ConstructorCalled;
    protected static void OnConstructorCalled(ConstructorCalledEventArgs e) => ConstructorCalled?.Invoke(e.Sender, e);
}

public class ConstructorCalledEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public object Sender;
    public ConstructorCalledEventArgs(object sender)
    {
        Sender = sender;
    }
}

public delegate void ConstructorCalledEventHandler(object sender, ConstructorCalledEventArgs e);
```

My BaseView Looks like this

```
    protected ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<TObject>> ObservableCollectionCollector = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<TObject>>();
    protected BaseView()
    {
        ObservableCollection<TObject>.ConstructorCalled += OnCollectionDeclared;
    }

    private void OnCollectionDeclared(object sender, ConstructorCalledEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is ObservableCollection<TObject>)
        {
            ObservableCollectionCollector.Add(sender as ObservableCollection<TObject>);
        }
    }
```

My problem right now is, that the event is not raised and I dont know why...

**EDIT:**

I have now chosen a different approach, because I had some issues with the generic classes and its event handlers. I have created a new static class, which handles now the constructor calls of both the Views and the ObservableCollections. It plays into my hands, that I am expecting only one type of the ObservableCollection class. Now my code looks like the following:

BaseView:

```
public class BaseView<TObject>
{
    public List<ObservableCollection<int>> ObservableCollectionCollector = new List<ObservableCollection<int>>();
    public BaseView()
    {
        ObservableCollectionCollector = CollectionHandler.GetAndRemoveCollection();
    }
}
```

ObservableCollection:

```
public class ObservableCollection<T> : System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public ObservableCollection()
        : base()
    {
        AddToCollectionHandler();
    }
    private void AddToCollectionHandler()
    {
        if (this is ObservableCollection<int>)
        {
            CollectionHandler.AddToCollection(this as ObservableCollection<int>);
        }
    }
}
```

and my CollectionHandler:

```
static class CollectionHandler
{
    private static List<ObservableCollection<int>> collection = new List<ObservableCollection<int>>();
    public static List<ObservableCollection<int>> GetAndRemoveCollection()
    {
        List<ObservableCollection<int>> col = collection;
        collection = new List<ObservableCollection<int>>();
        return col;
    }
    public static void AddToCollection(ObservableCollection<int> item) => collection.Add(item);
}
```

btw. a child view could look like this:

```
public class ChildView : BaseView<string>
{
    ObservableCollection<int> collection = new ObservableCollection<int>();
    public ChildView()
        : base()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're creating the `ObservableCollectionCollector` instance in your class' field initializer.

Field initializers run before class constructor bodies, so that's running before you add the event handler.  You need to only create the instance after you handle the static event.

Comment: `When you create an object, you only get the actual instance after its constructor finishes.` Not strictly true.  You have access to the object instance *in the constructor*, which is where the OP is adding the handler.  Of course, they're still adding it too late, even though it's still in the constructor.

Comment: Why should that be of concern with a static event?

Comment: @RandRandom: Oops; I missed that part.

Comment: Dont really understand your answer, but it smells fishy. Just cant point the finger on it. Why should initializing ``ObservableCollectionCollector`` have anything to do with the event, dont see the mistake?!?

Comment: @RandRandom The event is fired when it's initialized, because it fires the event in its constructor.  When it's initialized is when it calls the constructor.

Comment: BUT, he never initializes his ``ObservableCollection``. What you are talking about is an ``ObservableCollection`` of his ``ObservableCollection``. Or? I think his code is missing code that acutally initializes ``ObservableCollection`` that could potentially be added into his ``ObservableCollectionCollector``. Or do you think he actually wants the instance of ``ObservableCollectionCollector`` inside of ``ObservableCollectionCollector`` ?

Comment: @Servy see above comment

Comment: @RandRandom The line `protected ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<TObject>> ObservableCollectionCollector = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<TObject>>();` calls the `ObservableCollection<T>` constructor.

Comment: thanks for the disscussion, I have now chosen an other approach, which works for me and updated my question with my solution